# How can I order my db2 recursive sql to display the levels in a BOM by parent/child relationship

Tags: recursion, db2, common-table-expression

The following query gets all the results but does not group them correctly such as:

```
01 xxx
   02 bbb
      03 ccc
   02 ddd
      03 eee
      03 fff
         04 ggg
   02 hhh
01 yyy
etc
```

My results are displaying in ascending level order

```
WITH EXPL (LEVEL,  I_TC_ITEM_ID, I_TC_PARNT_ITEM_ID ) AS
(
SELECT 1 as LEVEL,
     ROOT.I_TC_ITEM_ID,  ROOT.I_TC_PARNT_ITEM_ID 
      FROM   DVMP.TC_PTV ROOT
   WHERE  
            ROOT.C_VARIANT = DVMP.C_VARIANT AND
            ROOT.I_TC_ITEM_ID  = DVMP.I_TC_ITEM_ID 
    UNION ALL
      SELECT LEVEL + 1,
        CHILD.I_TC_ITEM_ID, CHILD.I_TC_PARNT_ITEM_ID
      FROM   EXPL PARENT, DVMP.TC_PTV CHILD
      WHERE  CHILD.I_TC_PARNT_ITEM_ID  = PARENT.I_TC_ITEM_ID AND
             CHILD.C_VARIANT = DVMP.C_VARIANT 
                 )
     SELECT * 
     FROM     EXPL 
order by  level, I_TC_PARNT_ITEM_ID
```

A partial result gets:

```
LEVEL   I_TC_ITEM_ID    I_TC_PARNT_ITEM_ID
1   FC00ABF40383    FC00ABF39972
2   FC00ABF40384    FC00ABF40383
2   FC00ABF40385    FC00ABF40383
2   FC00ABF40386    FC00ABF40383
3   FC00AAA92586    FC00ABF40384
3   FC00ABI44739    FC00ABF40384
3   FC00ABI44739    FC00ABF40384
3   FC00ABY43106    FC00ABF40384
3   AGV21336    FC00ABF40385
3   FC00AAA11475    FC00ABF40385
3   FC00AAA11499    FC00ABF40385
3   FC00AAW37134    FC00ABF40385
3   FC00AAZ81249    FC00ABF40385
3   FC00ABD51310    FC00ABF40385
3   FC00ABD51315    FC00ABF40385
3   FC00ABD51338    FC00ABF40385
3   FC00ABS71006    FC00ABF40385
3   FC00ABS71019    FC00ABF40385
3   FC00AAA92586    FC00ABF40386
3   FC00ABI44739    FC00ABF40386
3   FC00ABI44739    FC00ABF40386
3   FC00ABY43105    FC00ABF40386
```

The results I would like would be like this:

```
LEVEL   I_TC_ITEM_ID    I_TC_PARNT_ITEM_ID
1   FC00ABF40383    FC00ABF39972
    2   FC00ABF40384    FC00ABF40383
        3   FC00ABI44739    FC00ABF40384
        3   FC00ABI44739    FC00ABF40384
        3   FC00ABY43106    FC00ABF40384
    2   FC00ABF40385    FC00ABF40383
        3   AGV21336    FC00ABF40385
        3   FC00AAA11475    FC00ABF40385
        3   FC00AAA11499    FC00ABF40385
        3   FC00AAW37134    FC00ABF40385
    2   FC00ABF40386    FC00ABF40383
        3   FC00AAA92586    FC00ABF40386
        3   FC00ABI44739    FC00ABF40386
          4   FC00ABI49612  FC00ABI44739
            5   FC00ABZ53105    FC00ABI49612
```

Comment: Please, edit your question with some data sample of relevant columns only (like parent_id, child_id, desc), the result you get and the result you want. Your long SQL query is not useful without actual data. To order the result properly, you may use an artificial "chain" column where you have a delimited string representation of all parent IDs of current row, which you use in the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort the rows according to the "path" that is formed from parent to child, to grandchild, etc. you can assemble this path while selecting the rows. Then sorting is trivial.

For example, I added the `ordering` column for sorting purposes:

```
with
expl (level, i_tc_item_id, i_tc_parnt_item_id, ordering) as (
    select
      1 as level,
      root.i_tc_item_id,
      root.i_tc_parnt_item_id,
      '/' || root.i_tc_item_id
    from dvmp.tc_ptv root
    where root.c_variant = dvmp.c_variant
      and root.i_tc_item_id = dvmp.i_tc_item_id
  union all
    select
      level + 1,
      child.i_tc_item_id,
      child.i_tc_parnt_item_id,
      parent.ordering || '/' || child.i_tc_item_id
    from expl parent, dvmp.tc_ptv child
    where child.i_tc_parnt_item_id = parent.i_tc_item_id
      and child.c_variant = dvmp.c_variant
  )
select
  repeat('.   ', level - 1) || -- to indent according to level
  i_tc_item_id || ' - ' ||
  i_tc_parnt_item_id
from expl
order by ordering
```

Comment: Executing this I get <eb1>SQL0206N  "EXPL.ORDERING" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703

State:S0022,Native:-206,Origin:[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64]</eb1>  When I take out ordering the query will run but in the exact order my original result was

Comment: @Munther Fixed the typo. Please try again.